# Требования для работы xcode

Tags: xcode, mac

Добрый день.

Хочу купить б/у мак для обучения в Xcode. Бюджет очень маленький. 
Рассматриваю вариант macbook air late 2010. Хватит ли 2гб оперативы хотя бы для того, чтоб просто поучится.
Просьба подсказать, каких системных требований будет достаточно для работы с Xcode. Спасибо.

Comment: А установка хакинтоша на виртуалку не рассматривается?

Comment: @hook_from_god, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: @iksuy, на виртуалку ставится мак, не обязательно хак

Comment: По личному опыту: для виртуалки однозначно нужен ssd, иначе нереально нормально работать, в остальном приемлемо. Если имеется норм PC - однозначно ставить Хак. Есть деннежка на миник - еще лучше... И так далее...

Comment: Спасибо большое, уже действительно задумался для начала на виртуалку поставить.

Answer (score 2):

На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа.
Для современной разработки, как мне кажется, важна не столько быстрота процессора (они все не медленные, в целом), сколько размерность ОЗУ. Поэтому я бы на вашем месте выбрал какой-нибудь mac mini (того же 10-го года), куда затем бы добавил нужное количество оперативной памяти + (в идеале) SSD.

Comment: Спасибо больше.

Comment: Да, ssd решает, оперативы 2гб однозначно мало - 8 минимум, имхо

Comment: Боюсь, что ХCode потребует OS X, а OS X, хоть и станет на 2 гигах, но он там умрет. Я вынужден был проапгрейдить свой Mac Mini до 8 гигов.